# Data bound context menu does not populates items when button is pressed on datagrid row in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, prism

I have a datagrid bound to an observable collection named 'ListOfEmployeeDetails'. The data-grid has three columns namely - 'Name', 'Date Of Birth' and 'Experience'. On the each cell of the third column (i.e. Experience) I have placed a button which should display a list of projects the employee has worked on during his/her experience.

I am unable to populate the list of projects when the button is clicked on the data-grid Row.

Here's what I have tried:

EmployeeDetails.Xaml

```
<Datagrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfEmployeeDetails}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date Of Birth"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Experience">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button 
            x:Name = "DropDownButton" 
            Tag="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext}"                    
            Command="{Binding  Path=DataContext.LoadDropDownMenu,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType= {x:Type DataGrid}}}"                                                                                                   
            CommandParameter="{Binding EmpId }">                     
            <Button.ContextMenu>
               //TODO: Need to display the list of Project Names for selected Employee ID
            </Button.ContextMenu>
          </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>  
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</Datagrid>
```

EmployeeDetailsViewModel.cs

```
public class EmployeeDetailsModel
{
  public string EmpId { get; set; }
  public string EmpName { get; set; }
  public string EmpDOB { get; set; }
  public string EmpExperience { get; set; }
  public  ObservableCollection<ProjectModel> ListOfProjects { get; set; }
}

private ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetailsModel> _ListOfEmployeeDetails;          
public  ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetailsModel>  ListOfEmployeeDetails          
{
   get { return _ListOfEmployeeDetails; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _ListOfEmployeeDetails, value); }
}

public ICommand LoadDropDownMenu
{
  get { return new DelegateCommand(LoadProjectDetails); }
}

private void LoadProjectDetails(object obj)
{
  ListOfProjects.Clear();    
  foreach(var employeeDetail in ListOfEmployeeDetails)
  {
    if(employeeDetail.EmpId == obj.ToString())
    {
      ListOfProjects.Add(role);
    }       
  }  
}

public class ProjectModel
{
  public string ProjectName { get; set; }
  public string ProjectID { get; set; }
}
```

What changes I should do to populate the list of project names in the context 
menu. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to tell the UI that collection is changed

Comment: @Polly My Datagrid is already binded to an Observable collection. Is there still any need for INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: You're populating the context menu of the button by pressing it? That's rather strange. But the context menu _should_ have entries after you clicked the button.

Comment: @Haukinger Is there any way i can populate the context menu after button click ?